# Keeping natural search and direct load stats using javascript redirects

Tags: javascript, seo, http-referer, web-analytics

On our site we drive all traffic to the www subdomain where our desktop site resides.
We also have device detection in place to redirect mobile devices and tablets to the mobile (m.) subdomain and tablet (tablet.) subdomain respectively.

Due to technical constraints we are unable to use 301's from the serverside since we are very reliant on edge caching. For this reason we eploy a simplified device detection that makes a serverside roundtrip and returns a json package containing basic browser/device data and true/false if the user should be redirected.

If, based on this information, the user should be redirected, yet another ajax call is made to resolve the redirect URI. The redirect is then handled using javascript using window.location.href=[resolved uri]

The result is that all direct load and natural search is lost and is replaced by www. subdomain referrals. Is there a way to circumvent this problem without changes to the underlying architecture? I.e. a frontend method?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer will be no, not with JavaScript.

Comment: That's basically the same conclusion I've reached. Do you have any suggestions towards the next best thing?

Comment: Other than just replacing the entire page's content with an Ajax call and using HTml5 page state management to change the url, you are stuck needing to do the redirection on the server.